# Ionic serve doesn't work/ exits batch

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am struggling to get the `ionic serve` command working .
Right now whener I go into my project folder inside the cmd and run the command it gives me the following output:

```
Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser -
Ctrl+C to cancel
[01:44:47]  watch started ...
[01:44:47]  build dev started ...
[01:44:47]  clean started ...
[01:44:47]  clean finished in 6 ms
[01:44:47]  copy started ...
[01:44:47]  deeplinks started ...
[01:44:47]  deeplinks finished in 21 ms
[01:44:47]  transpile started ...
[01:44:50]  transpile finished in 3.19 s
[01:44:50]  preprocess started ...
[01:44:50]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms
[01:44:50]  webpack started ...
[01:44:50]  copy finished in 3.37 s
[01:44:55]  webpack finished in 5.10 s
[01:44:55]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[01:44:56]  sass finished in 974 ms
[01:44:56]  postprocess started ...
[01:44:56]  postprocess finished in 8 ms
[01:44:56]  lint started ...
[01:44:56]  build dev finished in 9.44 s
[01:44:57]  watch ready in 9.52 s
[01:44:57]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/

[OK] Development server running!
     Local: http://localhost:8100
     External: http://111.111.1.111:8100
     DevApp: foo@8100 on DESKTOP-11QG111
```

It seems to be working fine but it doesn't stay inside the batch, instead it just exits it and therefore the server is not running. I am confused on why it doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to be ok .. what do you get when you visit http://localhost:8100? What error do you see when “it does not work”?

Comment: I noticed sometimes if I run ionic serve with the WIFI turned off, it builds and serves but then the server stops unexpectedly. Are you running ionic serve with no internet access ?

Comment: By "it doesn't work" I mean that it starts the server but then stops it straight after. So when I go to localhost:8100 it doesn't display anything @MayankRJain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benfit of anyone stumbling onto this, the solution on Windows is to make sure that
`C:\windows\system32` is in the PATH environment variable